# conditional changes based on value of other column

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-manipulation

I am trying to change CMT value to 1 from 2 when EVID column is equal to 1, basically what i am trying to do is like this

when NEW$EVID==1 
then
NEW$CMT== NEW$CMT-1

but its not working

Comment: Please include a [mcve] of your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `ifelse`:

```
  NEW$CMT <- ifelse( NEW$EVID==1,  NEW$CMT-1, NEW$CMT)
```

Or you could use Boolean arithmetic:

```
  NEW$CMT <-  NEW$CMT -( NEW$EVID==1)*1
```

You should also realize the in R the "==" operator does not do assignment. And it's usually safer to use `all.equal` unless you know for a certainty that your values are integer. Consider this result:

```
seq(0,1, by=0.1) == (0:10)/10
 [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```